# Parsing dynamic key return null

Tags: json, swift, parsing, codable

I'm trying to Parse dynamic string key this Model

{
"6665": [
"3",
"1",
"",
"3",
"1"
]
}

i set Model like this :

```
struct PrivaciesResponseModel: Codable {
typealias privacyID = String?
   
   let id : privacyID
   let value : [String]
   
   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
       let dict = try container.decode([String:[String]].self)
       guard let key = dict.keys.first else {
           throw NSError(domain: "Decoder", code: 0, userInfo: [:])
       }
       id = key
       value = dict[key] ?? []
   }
```

}

but always response return with empty array

How can i handle this, and what's the Problem?

Comment: This works fine for me in a playground. Is that the complete json?

Comment: Off topic but you have declared id as an optional and yet you throw an error if it isn't present, maybe it shouldn't be optional then?

Answer (score 0):

**This is working in my end:**

```
struct DataModel: Decodable {
    let data: [String:[String]]
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        self.data = try container.decode([String:[String]].self)
    }
}
```

PS: After getting the data, loop throw key value of the Dictionary to get the dynamic keys.